# Getting StackTraceElement in groovy application

Tags: groovy

I have a piece of code that prints the current java file for logging purposes.

```
final StackTraceElement stackTraceElement = new Throwable().fillInStackTrace().getStackTrace()[2];
final String parentClassName = stackTraceElement.getFileName().replaceAll(".java", "");
final int lineNumber = stackTraceElement.getLineNumber();
```

I wrote something in groovy that uses the above code to print logs, it works, most of the time, however after couple of runs I'm starting to get NPE

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.bla.general.util.log.LogUtils.generateLogMessage(LogUtils.java:140)
        at com.bla.general.util.log.LogUtils.info(LogUtils.java:67)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor831.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.invoke(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:43)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.call(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:88)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
        at com.bla.AppVersionServiceImpl.getAppVersion(AppVersionServiceImpl.groovy:47)
```

When the following line is the originator:

```
LogUtils.info("Trying to get details for device hash ${deviceHash}");
```

I'm using tomcat and java 1.7 as my stack. After restarting Tomcat things get back to normal. 
It's my first endeavor to the dynamic world of JVM. I'll appreciate if you can enlighten me

Comment: I'm digging into it, is there any chance that GString are Memoize ?

Comment: GString is not memoized, but it is evaluated lazily. You could try to convert to String using `.toString()` (or simply use single quotes and plus) and see if it changes anything.

Comment: Any chance that the stacktrace element does not have a file name ?

Comment: Perhaps, I'm not sure -- groovy is a dynamic language so it sounds plausible. Whenever I see an NPE and don't understand why, I at least make sure that every single call is null-safe. The `LogUtils` code look like pure java, where that can be a pain. In groovy, it's often as simple as using the [safe-navigation operator](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/Operators#Operators-SafeNavigationOperator%28%3F.%29): `?.`